# Oracle SOA Suite Quick Start 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: soa-suite

I need to download Oracle SOA Suite 12c version 12.2.1.3.0, and I've already searched for options in the site but there's only the VM option. Is there any place where I can download this specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://edelivery.oracle.com/
Oracle SOA Suite 12.2.1.3.0 ( Oracle Integration Adapter for Siebel, Oracle Integration Continuous Availability )

Why not use the most recent version, 12.2.1.4?

Comment: I use it for personal projects, but the enterprise where I started to work uses the previous version of it. By the way, thank you very much. :)